# Attach a video in SKPSMTPMessage

Tags: ios, xcode, email, nsdocumentdirectory, skpsmtpmessage

I have a VideoClip.mp4 stored in my documents directory in my app.  I can successfully send an email with SKPSMTPMessage, (email, subject, body, ect.) but I am having trouble attaching the video.  I have already searched around a lot, but I will keep looking.  If anyone can help me, that would be appreciated very much.  Thank you!

This code (apparently) attaches an image, but I haven't been able to figure out how to manipulate it to attach a video:

```
NSString *image_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@\"Success\" ofType:@\"png\"];
NSData *image_data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:image_path];
NSDictionary *image_part = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @\"inline;\r\n\tfilename=\\"Success.png\\"\",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,
                            @\"base64\",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,
                            @\"image/png;\r\n\tname=Success.png;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0666\",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                            [image_data encodeWrappedBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,
                            nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a late answer, but hope it helps someone. Assuming you know a path to your video file from documents directory (`videoPath`), here's the code:

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: videoPath];

NSDictionary *videoPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"video/quicktime;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"video.mov\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                                     @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"video.mov\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,[videoData encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
```

Then you can attach it to a `SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg` object like this (assuming you have the rest of `testMsg` required properties set, like credentials etc):

```
testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: videoPart,nil];
```