# What's the difference between encodeBase64ForData and encodeWrappedBase64ForData when using SKPSMTPMessage

Tags: objective-c, base64

In my app, I need to attach a video using SKPSMTPMessage. At first, I learned from [Dunja's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802543/2741596),

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: videoPath];

NSDictionary *videoPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"video/quicktime;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"video.mov\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                                     @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"video.mov\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,[videoData encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
```

but it's just can't work out. I tried all the solutions as I can imagined. Finally, I changed the encode type of videoData:
from

> ... [videoData encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey ...

to

> ... [videoData encodeWrappedBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey ...

and it works!

I have no idea what's the difference between this two api, can anyone help me out? Thank Dunja again, I learned a lot from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this answer: [GMail won't open .txt attachment created by iPhone App, Depending on Size - I think There's a Bug in my MIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114815/gmail-wont-open-txt-attachment-created-by-iphone-app-depending-on-size-i-th)

A function called **encodeBase64ForDataWrapped adds line breaks**. 
Perhaps you should be calling that instead, and if your attachment is sufficiently long the long base64 line is confusing somebody.

Here you can see the source code of both: http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/source/browse/trunk/SMTPSender/Classes/NSData%2BBase64Additions.m

Comment: You are quite right, encodeBase64ForDataWrapped solved my problems, and this function add line breaks to my videoDatas as you said.But I really want to know if these link breaks are the only difference, And should I always using encodeBase64ForDataWrapped in stead of encodeBase64ForData?

Comment: If you take a look at the source code you'll see, that the encodeBase64ForDataWrapped tried to use encodeBase64ForData first - so I mean, you can use always this one instead of encodeBase64ForData.