# Send an email from iOS application without using MFMailCompose UI

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, mfmailcomposer

Is there a way to send an email from iOS application without using MFMailCompose UI.

I need to send an email with a small (1.5mb) video but using a custom UI. This is not an app that is going to end up in app store because it's going to be in a kiosk environment. So I can use private APIs.

The reason that I cannot use MFMailCompose is multi-part.

1) UI is not customisable enough for my specific needs.

2) When you tap on EmailTo field and start typing it populates previously entered email addresses or email addresses in contacts list. (Shown in Figure_1). I need to get rid of this functionality.

3) You can also add additional emails from your contact list by tapping 'Plus Button' at the end of the TextField which will again show you your contact list.(Shown in Figure_2). I need to get rid of this functionality too.

But still, I would want to use the attaching video functionality that MFMailCompose provides and I don't want to use a web service to do this, as uploading these video onto some other servers maybe a privacy concern for many users.

Is there any private ios APIs that I can use to archive this. Use MFMailCompose functionality without the UI.

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Figure_1 : 
[image]

Figure_2 : 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SKPSMTPMessage`, it's not private though. [Git Hub](https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage). As far as video is concerned i hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642087/attach-a-video-in-skpsmtpmessage) question can help

Comment: Wow. Your a life saver, Man. Spot on. Thanks. Works like a charm. I did encounter crashes after each email was send, but managed to fix that. Again, thanks for the quick help.